# How do we express the concept of having something done in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, participio

Here are a few samples of to have something done:

> I am going to have my house painted.
>
> I want to have my office cleaned.
>
> I will have him hospitalized if he appears suicidal.

Each of the above examples could be expressed in a way that avoids the verb "to have" (such as "quiero que me limpien la oficina..."), but is there a way to express these ideas without such circumlocution?

Comment: Welcome Serveto to [spanish.se]! We hope we see you here often :)

Comment: Yes, great question!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome--I think I'm going to enjoy it here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't vouch for other regions, but in Mexico at least, there is

**mandar a (verb)**

Examples:

> Mandé a hacer un traje. | *I'm having a suit made / made to order /
>   custom made.* OR *I ordered a suit*.
>
> ¿Se puede mandar a limpiar la oficina? | *Would it be possible to have the office cleaned?*
>
> Vamos a mandar a pintar la casa. | *We're going to have the house
>   painted.*

*Notes:*

- In Mexico custom work by a seamstress or tailor (or even a shoemaker) is more accessible than in the US, where a custom dress is typically very expensive and is generally only found in a wedding context.
- About the office example: I phrased it as a question, since cultural expectations of politeness would lead one to avoid sounding too direct.

For the hospitalization example, I'm guessing the action would not be external, as in the other examples.  So I think this would be expressed, in most cases, like this:

> Lo tendré que internar si lo veo suicida.
>   | *I'll have to put him in the hospital if he seems suicidal.*

**Extension to *ordering* an item, by mail order or internet shopping**

> Mandé a pedir la lavadora porque por acá no surten el modelo que me interesaba. | *I ordered the washing maching because the model I wanted wasn't available locally.*

Comment: That is exactly what we use in Colombia too. As for the OP's  examples **I am going to have my house painted.** _Voy a mandar pintar mi casa_ , 
**I want to have my office cleaned.** _Quiero mandar a limpiar mi oficina_ , 

**I will have him hospitalized if he appears suicidal.** _Lo voy a mandar a hospitalizar si lo veo suicida_

Comment: @DGaleano - Hope you don't mind - I revised the suicidal example using your simplified expression.  (This is a topic that never came up in conversation that could remember.)  Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely no problem. I always make comments trying to add and help. And I never use **®** jajajajaja

Comment: @DGaleano - ¿Marca registrada?  It took me a minute -- good one!

Answer (score 2):

You can use "hacer que" + action, like this:

> I am going to have my house painted.
>   → *Voy a hacer que pinten mi casa.*
>   → *Me voy a hacer pintar la casa.*
>   → *Voy a hacer que me pinten la casa.*
>
> I want to have my office cleaned.
>   → Quiero hacer que limpien mi oficina.
>   → Quiero hacer que me limpien la oficina.
>
> I will have him hospitalized if he appears suicidal.
>   → Voy a hacer que lo hospitalicen si muestra tendencias suicidas.
>   → Haré que lo hospitalicen si muestra tendencias suicidas.
>   → Lo haré hospitalizar si muestra tendencias suicidas.

And similar variations.

Please consider that this is not the usual way to say such things in Spanish, at least in my experience: normally you would just say "Me van a pintar la casa", "Quiero que me limpien la oficina" or "Lo hospitalizaré si muestra tendencias suicidas", directly using the main verb instead.

Comment: Also (feel free to add): *«(Me) voy a hacer pintar la casa»*, *«Lo voy a hacer hospitalizar si...»*, etc.